# PHP PDO Memory Limit

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, memory-limit

Good day everyone. I have this function:

```
public function get_subcategory_name($parent_id){
    if($parent_id !=0){
        $data = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT *FROM `" . Config::get('mysql/tbl_categories') . "` WHERE `id` = $parent_id");
        foreach($data->results() as $dt){
            if($dt->parent_category_id == 0){
                $name =  $dt->name;
            }else{
                $name = Category::get_subcategory_name($dt->parent_category_id) . $dt->name;
            }
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
    return $name ." <i class='fa fa-angle-double-right'></i> ";
}
```

With this function I want to grab the subcategory names, and I have the rule when the category has no parent it will return `false`, but for some reason this function works and never stops and I have a memory limit problem. I've tried a lot of ways but I can not find any solution, please help me if you can. Thank you.

Comment: Please post the class definition of `DB`. I suspect something in the `results()` function incorrectly handles row fetching resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: ...and post the relevant parts of the `Category` class.

Comment: If `DB` is a singleton wrapper around `PDO`, please, please get rid of it. Singeltons in PHP are really quite pointless. If `DB` somehow _extends_ `PDO`: [ditch it ASAP](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29362/very-simple-php-pdo-class/29394#29394). Oh, and `id = $parent_id`<-- can be an injection vulnerability, use prepared statements. BTW: The memory limit issue isn't likely to be `PDO` related. `$data->results()` is probably the cause of your woes, resulting in an infinite loop. Post more code

Comment: `var_dump($dt->parent_category_id)` before the `if()` test, and confirm what you're getting. if it's not 0, then the loop'll never stop

Answer (score 0):

you can allocate temporarily extra memory by using is

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '750M');
```

Comment: "never stops", in other words an infinite loop. you'd need infinite memory to "fix" the problem...

Comment: If the code is broken, don't increase the resources it can consume, but rather fix the code

Comment: yes @Marc B you are right i am just give a example .Thank you for that